# Could a Stargate be used to destroy another Stargate?

Tags: stargate

Whenever a stargate is opened, we see some kind of blowback, which I'm told is called a "kawoosh".  If there is nothing blocking the surface of the event horizon, this forms and comes out from the Stargate, then snaps into the event horizon and is not seen again until the gate is opened again.

We've seen instances where this destroys different types of matter.

Could this kawoosh be used to destroy another Stargate?

For instance, if you are able to transport a gate to a planet where there's another and deactivate the DHD on the first one, and position the second one correctly, wouldn't the kawoosh destroy the 1st gate?

My thought is that if that were possible, it would have been possible to destroy segments of the Ori super-gate using that method.

Would that have let them use a stargate itself as a weapon to destroy almost anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "kawoosh" is an [unstable wormhole](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_vortex). It can supposedly disintegrate "virtually anything".

If we go by known physics and assume that this is a real wormhole with a real event horizon, and assume that the Ori super-gate is not made of some sort of exotic matter, it can definitely have a bite taken out of it using this method.

However, event horizons in the Stargate universe are not quite right -- if they were, you will never be able to pull your hand out once you put it in. Instead, Stargates use a combination of wormhole plus matter-energy conversion. In this case, it appears to be the matter-energy conversion mechanism working without a stable wormhole. So the matter disintegrates and converts into energy, but goes nowhere (we know it is not just vaporized because once a wormhole activated underground and left a normal-pressure cavity large enough for Teal'C to enter and dig himself to the surface).

So either way, this could have been used against the Ori gate.

Comment: Of course that gate was huge. It probably would have taken a long time to damage it to the point that it could not have functioned any more.

Comment: @Xantec: Destroying a single ship, which could have been done with one kawoosh, would have broken the chain.

Comment: I (and I think @TangoOversway as well) assumed that the ring is one giant continuous coil. Breaking it at one point is all it takes, in that case.

Comment: @HNL: That's close.  I figured either that was the case, or they could pick two (or four) strategic locations on the super-gate and destroy those points, leaving separate sections in space that could be pulled apart.

Comment: It comes down to what it takes to destroy one of the super gate segments.  As each segment not only contains what is necessary for the whole gate to function, they also have their own independent power, propulsion, and navigation systems.  And knowing the Ori, they also have their uber shields without the primary weapon weakness.  All around a tough nut to crack.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest Yes, it seems we did not account for shields. Shields may in fact be able to repel an unstable vortex.

Comment: @HNL, except that Tealc used the tactic to destroy that Ori mothership *with it's shields up* so it's probably just something that was unanticipated since nobody commonly lugs stargates around as weapons. Not to mention it's got such a short effective range the concern for it could've been discarded out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the supergate would have fallen under the "things the kawoosh can't destroy" otherwise that seems like an easy solution that was overlooked, unless the writers totally forgot about it.

On the other hand, if the supergate was destroyed, then the ori would just have constructed one somewhere else.  Notice how once the sg-1 team blocked the supergate by dialing in from pegasus no more ori entered the milky way, until it was deactivated.  You know how you can't dial into a stargate near one that is already active.  I think the same principle holds for intergalactic gates, but one a much larger scale.  If there is one intergalactic gate that is active than no other intergalactic gates can be active in proximity, perhaps in the whole galaxy.  Therefore blocking the supergate would prevent the ori from getting to the milky way, not destroying it.

Comment: This seems more like random guessing than anything based on canon

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To , we **know** it stopped the Ori the only question is if that's because they couldn't overcome it or the writers dropped the ball. A better question is why didn't the Ori either turn off the supergate or destroy it themselves if it could be. But then they hadn't even bothered to guard it which would've prevented the issue to begin with

Answer (score 2):

The Kawoosh is an "[unstable vortex created by the formation of a wormhole](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_vortex)" and is unrelated to the "event horizon" that performs the [matter-energy conversion](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate#Matter_transmission) employed by the stargates.

[The kawoosh from a supergate was capable of destroying an Ori warship](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Black_Hole), which would ostensibly be more heavily armored and shielded than ring segments of the supergate itself. This kawoosh would certainly be capable of destroying supergate ring segments.

However, this begs the follow-up question of how you get a regular stargate to create a kawoosh next to a supergate. [Due to how stargate priority or supersedence works](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate#Secondary_Stargates), the supergate would have priority for all inbound wormholes, and the Milky Way has no "puddle jumper DHD" for remote dialing a space gate for an outgoing wormhole. (Side note: there are puddle jumpers in the Milky Way, the time jumper from S8E13 and 1 temporarily brought from Pegasus in SGA S3E10. Both were kept in storage/research and not used in regular missions.)

Simply put, dialing an outbound wormhole with a space gate in the milky way is not a trivial task and dialing an inbound wormhole to a nearby standard gate would likely not work at all.

Such a solution would have made SG-1 S10E3 last all of about 30 seconds. The priority/supersedence point was also completely ignored in that episode after being firmly established throughout the series. All they had to do to use your solution would be to turn their destination standard gate around to face the supergate and **BOOM**.

Most likely this was simply a solution that the writers overlooked or chose not to employ as it would detract from the series' drama. As I said, an entire episode would have been reduced to 30 seconds.

Comment: I would make two points. First I don't think we know if the Ori warships are made of a more dense material or shielded more than the supergates. Second, in the episode you mention, s10 e3, the SGC had to get a milky way gate to jump to the supergate to keep it open; which tells us that the milky way gates would actually supersede the supergates, likey because they supergates are "out of network." The reason the episode was more than 30 seconds is because they needed to dial in from Pegasus with a gate near a black hole to establish the longer than 30 minute shut down time.

Comment: I agree with you that the kawoosh and event horizon are completely unrelated however!

Comment: @Odin1806 - Interesting points. 1: It's not the density of the Ori ship or supergate material so much as its the engineering. The supergate would not be able to sport armor or shields because the function of the supergate would destroy such. (It's possible the Ori could invent technology to overcome this, but we see no evidence of it in the show.) #2 - The Milky Way gate superseding the Ori gate is exactly why that episode ignores precedent; it's established that newer gates supersede old gates throughout the series. There was no "in universe" explanation given for the inconsistency.